# Parse xml/HTML string with Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parsing, dom, xpath, parse-platform

I need to parse an XML/HTML file within the cloud-code of parse.com.

I've got a string which contains the source-code of the html file.

I've already tried multiple frameworks like jsdom etc, but nothing seems to work in the Parse.com-cloudcode environment.

This code for example results in an error in the jsdom-file. But I've got no idea what the real problem is. Because the "<" ">" tags are set correctly in the jsdom.js-file.

```
var jsdom = require("cloud/jsdom.js");
var window = jsdom.jsdom().createWindow();
var jquery = require("cloud/jquery-1.11.2.min.js")(window);

var dataHtml = httpResponse.text;

response.success(jquery.$(dataHtml).find("body").text());
```

Error:

```
{"code":141,"error":"Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \u003c in jsdom.js:5\n    at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:9:21)
```

Is there another possibility to parse a string with XPath or dom in the parse.com-cloudcode?

Answer (score 6):

This answer can be too late, but I just realized a bundle of cheerio module that works with Parse.

Example:

```
var cheerio = require('cloud/cheerio.bundle.js'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();
//=> <h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>
```

You can get it [here](https://github.com/icaliman/parse_cheerio).