# Parse.com error with document.createElement('script')

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, cloud, jsonp

I'm trying to use this code with Parse.Cloud.beforeSave...

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
```

and I get this: **Result: ReferenceError: document is not defined**

How can I use *document* with Parse.Cloud?

My code:

```
function getJSONP(url, success) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url.replace('callback=', 'callback=do');
        document.head.appendChild(script);

        do = function (data) {
            success(data);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Parse Cloud code does not run in the browser. It runs on the server where the DOM does not exist. Why are you trying to use the DOM?

Comment: I'm trying to download a JSONP...                                                              function getJSONP(url, success) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url.replace('callback=', 'callback=do');
        document.head.appendChild(script);

        do = function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            success(data);
        }
    }

Comment: Not sure if Parse allows it, but you could just make a normal HTTP request and `eval` the response. JSONP is only used to circumvent the same-origin policy in the browser. There is no need for script tags on the server side, just make the HTTP request.

Comment: I wonder if you can somehow use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) on Parse.com? Alternatively, does [this question and answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908054/parse-xml-html-string-with-parse-com)?

Comment: Thanks! @FelixKling the solution is Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: myURL,
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.data);
        response.success();
    }, error: function(httpResponse) {
        response.error('Request failed...');
     }
});
```